# EasyAdminBundle: how to redirect back to form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4, easyadmin

In the admin panel created with EasyAdminBundle, the administrator can create a new Booking. I want to add an availability check (via a service) before this new booking instance is persisted into the database. If this check returns false, the admin should be redirected back to the form.

I have extended the `EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController` class and overridden the `persistEntity()` function:

```
...
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController as BaseAdminController;

class BookingController extends BaseAdminController
{
    private $availabilityService;

    public function __construct(AvailabilityService $availabilityService)
    {
        $this->availabilityService = $availabilityService;
    }

    protected function persistEntity($booking)
    {
        $checkin = Carbon::instance($booking->getCheckin());
        $checkout = Carbon::instance($booking->getCheckout());

        if($this->availabilityService->checkAvailability($checkin, $checkout)) {
            parent::persistEntity($booking);
        } else {
            return false; //redirect back to the form
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution (Vyctorya led me to the correct path). Make sure that you are only calling the check on the concerned entity with `instanceof`. If the check fails, redirect the user to the edit form by passing in the referer request header.

```
  if ($newForm->isSubmitted() && $newForm->isValid()) {

     if ($entity instanceof Booking) {
        $formData = $newForm->getData();

        if(!$this->availabilityService->checkAvailability($formData->getCheckin(), $formData->getCheckout())) {
           return $this->redirect($this->request->headers->get('referer'));
         }
      }

    return $this->redirectToReferrer();
  }
```

Comment: Can you please expand your answer. It's not understandable for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should override the newAction instead and edit

```
if ($newForm->isSubmitted() && $newForm->isValid()) {
```

to something like this

```
if ($newForm->isSubmitted() && $newForm->isValid()) {
   if ($this->availabilityService->checkAvailability($entity)) {
```

If that does not fit your needs you could write an EventListener for EasyAdminEvents::PRE_PERSIST and return a redirect to newAction. An EventListener would be more complex as the event gets dispatched on new entities and edited ones.